# Irreducible algebraic sets with intersecting parts

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, algebraic-curves

Let $V = V(F)$ be an irreducible hypersurface in $A^n(k)$.

To show:

If $W$ is an irreducible algebraic set in $A^n(k)$ with $V \subset W$, then $V = W$.

The ideas I got so far:

Since $V, W$ are irreducible, the generated ideals, $I(V)$ and $I(W)$, are prime.
Since $V, W$ are algebraic sets with $V \subset W$, $I(V) \supset I(W)$.

Is there a possibility to proof $I(V) \subset I(W)$ with the help of the information that those ideals are prime / $V, W$ are irreducible?

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's think: the most annoying thing to say is you probably want $W$ not to be all of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$.

Now, the inclusion $V(f) \subseteq V(I)$ is equivalent to $(f) \supseteq I$. Suppose $(f) \supsetneq I$, i.e. $f \notin I$. Well, take any nonzero $i \in I$, and write it as $f \cdot p$. By the fact that $I$ is prime, we deduce $p \in I$. Writing $p = f \cdot p'$, we deduce $p'$ is in $I$. Continuing in this fashion, we deduce $p$ is divisible by arbitrarily high powers of $f$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer already! So basically you are trying to find an element that is an element of I, but not an element of (f). Since this is not possible (by the procedure you just posted), I can say that (f) = I?

Comment: Almost, but slightly different - we started with $V(f) \subseteq V(I)$, so we already know that $I \subseteq (f)$. What I'm showing is that $f$ also has to be in $I$, so the inclusion is an equality.

Comment: you chose $i$ out of $I$ with $i = f*p$. How do we know that a product of $f$ and $p$ is in $I$? And how do we know that we can reproduce every power of $f$ if $I$ is not every element out of $k[X1,...,Xn]$? Do you think there is even a solution with the help of Hilberts Nullstellensatz? There is a one-to-one correspondence between the irreducible algebraic sets and the prime ideals.